# Angularjs directive get data from url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i define a directive in angularjs that have a url to fetch data from data base. i display part of code.
my directive is :

```
app.directive('getData', function() {

return {
 restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    url: '@',
    suggestion: '=data'
   },
  controller: ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){
    $http.get($scope.url)
      .success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);// display data 
        $scope.Items = data;
      });
   })
  template:
           <li\
          suggestion\
              ng-repeat="suggestion in suggestions track by $index"\
          </li>\
}
```

now when i create a directive such as this in html

```
<get-data url="/public/getEmployee" data="Items"></get-data>
```

but no data display in it, while same code in directive controller be in an angularjs controller work correctly.

Comment: you directive definition name is `getData` and your usage is `my-directive`?

Comment: @Chandermani it is mistake in type.

Comment: If you're going to use your fetched data in other places you should use a service or factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the http request inside the directive and getting the data inside the directive, so you do not need to pass the `suggestion` variable in scope.

Directly use `Items` array in the template `item in Items track by $index`.

Isolated scope variable passed in  `scope` property are used to get data from external dependencies.

And your directive usage should be

```
<get-data url="/public/getEmployee"></get-data>
```